# Remove rows in R dataframe that are duplicates, first in group, share ID with first in group or all of the above

Tags: r, date, duplicates, match, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with dates and identifiers. I want to filter this dataframe to end up with rows that have 1) consecutive dates to others in the original dataframe, 2) are not the first of a group of consecutive dates, 3) do not have the same ID as a row that was first of a group of consecutive dates after the date that it was first, 4) are deduplicated based on ID. For example

```
Date <-  as.Date('2019.01.01', '2019.01.02', '2019.01.03', '2019.01.04', '2019.01.10',  '2019.01.11', '2019.01.12', '2019.01.13', '2019.01.18', '2019.01.22', '2019.01.27', ' 2019.01.28', '2019.01.30')
ID <- c('A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'F', 'D', 'F', 'F', 'C', 'G')
df <- data.frame(Date, ID)

 Date        ID
 2019.01.01  A
 2019.01.02  A
 2019.01.03  C
 2019.01.04  C
 2019.01.10  D
 2019.01.11  E
 2019.01.12  A
 2019.01.13  F
 2019.01.18  D
 2019.01.22  F
 2019.01.27  F
 2019.01.28  C
 2019.01.30  G
```

To end up with

```
     Date        ID
     2019.01.03  C
     2019.01.11  E
     2019.01.13  F
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is `C` still in your resulting data.frame? `2019.01.03  C`, `2019.01.04  C` and `2019.01.28  C` meet your first three conditions but C isn't unique in the then remaining data.frame,

Comment: Edited for clarity. This was intended to commuictae that the resulting dataframe is deduplicated so only one row is present per ID. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: So you take the first `C` removing the rest?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we define the elements, that are "first of a group":

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

first_of_groups <- df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as_date(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(grp_cond_3 = cumsum((Date - lag(Date, default = first(Date))) != 1)) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  slice_min(Date)
```

We need this data.frame to remove this elements. Next we build up the data.frame:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(Date = as_date(Date),
         condition_1 = Date == lag(Date) + 1,
         condition_2 = replace_na(condition_1, FALSE)) %>% 
  left_join(first_of_groups, by = "ID", suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% 
  mutate(condition_3 = is.na(Date.y) | Date < Date.y) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(condition_1, condition_2, condition_3) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  select(Date, ID) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Date       ID   
  <date>     <chr>
1 2019-01-03 C    
2 2019-01-11 E    
3 2019-01-13 F
```

Basically `condition_1` and `condition_2` are the same. We take the date and calculate the difference to the preceding date. If the difference equals 1 we know two things:

- it's not the first element of a group of consecutive days
- it has consecutative days

For the "first of groups" condition, we search for the rows in your dataset, whose difference with the preceeding row isn't 1. Assuming, that there aren't rows with the same date, we can build up a grouping number using `cumsum` from this information.

Next we filter for "real" groups, groups with more than one element. And we take the first element of those groups.

Using this `first_of_groups` data.frame we are able to build `condition_3` by left joining `first_of_groups` with our original dataframe. `condition_3` is met either there is no match for the `ID` in the `first_of_groups` data.frame (`is.na(Date.y)`) or the Date is lesser/smaller (lies before) the date of the `ID` becoming "first of a group".

The final `condition_4` is created by taking the first element per `ID` in the remaining data.frame.